# jQuery replace text on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file upload form on a site and i'd like to replace the form with the text "uploading..." whilst the file uploads. so far i have:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(form).submit(function(){
        $('#key').html("Uploading...");
    });
});
```

the submit part works because i got it to alert on submit and the .html part works because it will change the html when it's not in the submit function. The form is in a div with the id of "key".

Comment: I recommend renaming the submit button to 'Uploading...' and disable the button so it cannot be clicked again.

Comment: $(form).remove();
$('#key').html('Uploading');

But #key element must be outside the form one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="someForm"></form>
<div id="key" style="display:none">Uploading...</div>

$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#someForm').submit(function(){
        $('#key').show();
        $('#someForm').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Turns out changing the html of the form stops the form from working after you've submitted it, the hide and show works fine. thanks for the answer.